# HGST/Travelstar Z5K1000-1000 damaged from impact

Tags: hard-drive, asus-laptop, physical-damage

My little sister accidentally dropped my ASUS Q303U last night, and when i tried to boot it up, it wouldn't recognize the drive. I tried to plug it in to my tower PC, but it wasn't recognized either. It doesnt have any sign of shaking, vibrations, or activity, so I suspect that the RW head is pressed onto the platter, or that there is other physical damage inside the HDD.

So I did what anyone would usually do - substitude the HDD with one that is intact. I tried to install Windows 10 on that drive, but it wouldn't recognize the USB drive. Yes, I did make sure that i wrote the right install image (64-bit). But it never worked.

So, I want to know if it's safe to disassemble the broken HDD and fix it inside (or if it is, how), as I have **never** repaired an HDD before.

Help?

Comment: Don't ever dream of dismantling a hard drive, don't even think about it. Data recovery specialist is what you need, assuming you don't have a backup. They are expensive & will make no guarantees.

Comment: Is your questions about how to disassemble a HDD and repair?  Or is it why does your computer not recognize your drive?  These are two very different questions.

Answer (score -2):

It is safe to disassemble a HDD if you want to try to fix it, but you will likely be unsuccessful without a lot of experience as Tetsujin suggests.  You can readily find tutorials with the search phrase "HDD platter swap", there's even a wikiHow on the topic.

HOWEVER, you are presenting more than just one issue here.  It may not be just the hard drive.  "I tried to install Windows 10 on that drive, but it wouldn't recognize the USB drive."  This could be a simple procedural error (not setting the thing to boot from USB, not having the drivers for the system hardware, etc.) or it could be indicative of further damages to the Laptop.

I treat my technology like my bank accounts, but sometimes I need the accountant to look over my books.  Time to let a repair guy take a look?

Comment: I completely disagree that "It is safe to disassemble a HDD if you want to try to fix it,"   I hate being a "downer" and am all for fix it yourself but disassembling a HDD without a clean room and any knowledge and expecting anything good as a result is setting someone up for failure.  Physical hard drive recovery is extremely specialized if you have to go inside the casing.  Outside the casing, try to your hearts content but don't open the casing up if you want any chance of recovery.

Comment: @damon while I fully agree that opening a hard drive outside a clean room  is normally a bad idea, but just wanted to point out that it is conceivable that you could do this and recover data - occasionally.  Its place is as a "last ditch" effort with low, but non-zero chance of success when the cost of specialist services are out of reach.

Comment: Guys, a particle of dust on a HDD platter is the equivalent of an airplane crashing into a city. Without special lab equipment and proper sealing the attempt is futile.

Comment: @overmind It's true that a typical spec of dust is orders of magnitude taller then the distance between platters and disk and that is a massive risk, but it is sometimes still possible to pull data off. It is said that the centrifugal force of the platters can dislodge dust from the platters, and plenty of YouTube videos showing success.

Comment: With proper preparations, tools and skills, yes, it can be done.